# What is the best location to store the API Root Url in React JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using mern stack in a project I'm working on.

Currently I'm making requests to the rest api like so.

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/testimonials/');
```

The API is available at `http://localhost:5000/`

but when I will deploy this app that url will change.

With the current approach I have replace `http://localhost:5000/` with the live url.

Instead of doing that I want to store the root url in a variable.

What is the best location to store the API root in React JS?

So I can use it in every request I make and when I have to update the url I just have to update that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do two things ,

1. storing them in env variables by creating .env file for each environment

   [CRA - .env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

   Don't forget to prefix your names with REACT_APP_ , else it won't work
2. using proxy in package.json .(This is the preferred way of using api in docs)

   It avoids [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error as mentioned in docs

   [CRA - proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: I think I'll go with using proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use ***.env*** file to save the root url. ***.env*** should be located in the root directory.

.env file content:

```
rooturl=http://yourproductiondomain.com
```

and you can use process on your code:

```
const rooturl = process.env.rooturl || 'http://localhost:5000'; // for lcoalhost.. **.env** file does not work on localhost.
const { data } = await axios.get(rooturl + '/api/testimonials/');
```

Comment: dotenv is used in the server. not in the client I believe.